# Equivalent environment variable for PROTON_FORCE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE in lutris?

Tags: linux, wine

I would write `PROTON_FORCE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`=1 to active `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` for all executable on the wine bottle, if I were to use steam's proton. What's its equivalent command for standalone wine or lutris?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at [the source code](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/blob/c6a40b99477a577413ef5b93267017c6df5283df/proton#L483-L507) reveals these lines:

```
self.check_environment("PROTON_FORCE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE", "forcelgadd")
```

```
if "forcelgadd" in self.compat_config:
    self.env["WINE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE"] = "1"
```

As such, it looks like the equivalent is `WINE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`.